# how to make div like

Tags: html, css, firefox3.6

Ok. I want to create div which:
1. is as big as text is
2. but it has its minimal size and maximal one

And tell my why this line of CSS makes my height as max-height instead of size of text or minimal height ?

```
div#me{max-height:40%;min-height:20%;background-color:silver;}
```

full code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pl" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<html>
<style type="text/css">
html {width:100%;height:100%;}
html div{margin-left:3%;margin-top:1%;width:94%;height:100%;background-color:black;}
div#me{max-height:40%;min-height:20%;background-color:silver;}
</style>

<div>
<div id="me">
TEXT<br/>
TEXT<br/>
</div>



</div>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to add more information to your question. The code you've given does this: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/q7q88/ - try creating your own jsFiddle test case which represents your problem.

Comment: I want to set height to the smallest possibility without cutting text, but instead I get div as big as its possible(max-height). http://jsfiddle.net/bgtJk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/bgtJk/2/

The issue you had was that the rules for `html div` were being applied to **both `div`s**.

So, the inner `div` was being told to have `height: 100%`; not what you wanted, and the cause of your problem.

To fix it, I specified an `id` on the outer div.

Now, the `#me` `div` will vary in height depending on the content - from `min-height:20%` to `max-height:40%`, and anywhere in between depending on text height. If the text is too tall, it will spill over, instead of increasing the height of the `div`, [**like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/bgtJk/3/). That doesn't seem to be particularly desirable behaviour.

---

Are you sure you don't just want it like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/bgtJk/4/

The text will determine the height of the `div`.

---

Or like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/bgtJk/5/

The `div` will be at least `20%` high, but can grow as tall as needed.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I couldn't move forward without you.